# ¿Qué significa el .PHONY en los Makefiles?

Tags: makefile

Me he encontrado muchas veces con esto: `.PHONY` al final de los archivos `Makefile` y quisiera saber qué significa. Yo he usado `Makefiles` pero nunca he necesitado agregar eso.

Un ejemplo concreto de lo que encontré ahora:

```
.PHONY: \
  all \
  test \
  clean \
  release
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Traduciendo la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3574387/688393) de [George Y.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/431757/george-y) desde Stack Overflow a la pregunta [What is the purpose of .PHONY in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile). La explicación es sencilla y bastante buena.

---

Asumamos que tienes el target "install", el cual es muy común en los makefiles. Si no usas `.PHONY`, y existe un archivo llamado "install" en el mismo directorio que el Makefile, entonces el comando `make install` no hará nada. Esto ocurre porque Make interpreta la regla como "ejecuta esta-y-esta receta para crear el archivo llamado install". Como el archivo ya se encuentra allí, y las dependencias no han cambiado, no ocurrirá nada.

Sin embargo, si haces que el target "install" sea un PHONY, le indicarás a la herramienta `make` que el target es ficticio, y que el `make` no debería crear el archivo. Por lo tanto no verificará que el archivo "install" exista, lo cual significa que:

1. Su comportamiento no será alterado si el archivo realmente existe
2. El `stat()` extra no será llamado

Generalmente todos los targets en tu Makefile que no producen un archivo de salida con el mismo nombre que el nombre del target, deberían ser de tipo PHONY. Esto incluye típicamente a `all`, `install`, `clean`, `distclean`, etc.

---

Con el siguiente ejemplo de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145605/688393) sacada de la misma pregunta creada por [Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky) debería quedar más claro.

---

Estos targets especiales son llamados PHONY y puedes indicarle explícitamente a Make que no están asociados a archivos, por ejemplo:

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
  rm -rf *.o
```